# Bash evaluation of expression .[].[]

Tags: bash

Consider the following expression evaluations:

```
$ echo .
.
$ echo .[]
.[]
$ echo .[].
.[].
$ echo .[].[]
..                # <- WAT??
$ echo .[].[].
.[].[].
$ echo .[].[].[]
.[].[].[]
```

Can someone explain why `.[].[]` has this special behavior?

(Tested in bash `3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)` and `4.4.23(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-androideabi)`.

I suspect it has something to do with `..` being a valid "file" (the parent directory). But then why doesn't e.g. `.[].` produce the same result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `[]` creates a character class. Normally, `]` must be escaped (backslashed) to be included in the class, but you don't have to escape it if it immediately follows the opening bracket. Therefore, `[].[]` in fact means `[\].[]` which matches any of the characters `.`, `]`, and `[`.

You can verify it by creating files named `.]` and `.[`.

```
touch .\[ .\]
echo .[].[]  # .. .[ .]
```

Comment: Wow great (and fast!) explanation. So the reason that `.[].` doesn't yield the same result is that `[]` by itself isn't interpreted as a character class?

Comment: Exactly, as there's no need for an empty character class.